# A Complex Variable ODE

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

[image]suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on some domain $D$ satisfying $f'(z)=af(z) $ for some       >constant a. show that $f(z)=Ce^{az}$, for some constant $C$

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: Disregard those people asking for your work and all those ridiculous requests. On the other hand, I am pretty sure the question has been answered before. Did you use the search box?

Comment: First we know that $(e^x)'=e^x$. It depends on the definition of $e^x$ you begin with but pretty much all of them allow you to show that it is equal to its own derivative. Then put $g(x):=f(x)/e^{ax}$. Then $f(x)=e^{ax}g(x)$. Substitute in the differential equation. We get $g'(x)=0$, from where $g$ is a constant.

Comment: @PLKTU why is it ridiculous to ask for OP's work?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick 1) It serves no purpose. 2) It fills the page with irrelevant babbling (mainly from those asking and in rare cases from the OP explaining too). 3) The answer will be given regardless (always!!). 4) Makes the OP waste time in getting an answer. After all, what ever they did they have already done it. 5) More often than not, those asking are moved by a sense of authority or self-righteousness that IS ridiculous by itself. 6) If the OP judges, by itself, that some of its thoughts are important (or the OP just want them to be discussed) they will definitely post it.

Comment: i used CR equation to solve this problem let z=x+iy, f(z)=u+iv, then f′(z)=af(z）= du/dx+i dv/dx

Answer (score 2):

Since you showed no work, I am only going to get you started. Oberve, $f^\prime(z) = a f(z) \iff a = \frac{ f^\prime(z)}{f(z)}$. Integrate both sides. Reduce.

Comment: And if $f(z)=0$?

Comment: Then $f \equiv 0$, so to avoid trivialities assume this is not the case. Excellent point.

Comment: Why are you allowed to divide by $f$?

Comment: i used CR equation to solve this problem let z=x+iy, f(z)=u+iv, then f′(z)=af(z）= du/dx+i dv/dx  but, finally i do not know how to keep doing that.

Comment: Do you understand what Yiorgos did? His answer is better formulated than mine, as in it doesn't lose the singular solution $f \equiv 0$, and is the way you should think about the problem.

Comment: yes, i understood thank you

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the equation by $\mathrm{e}^{-az}$ (i.e., by the *integrating factor*) we obtain:
$$
0=\mathrm{e}^{-az}\big(f'(z)-af(z)\big)=\big(\mathrm{e}^{-az}f(z)\big)'.
$$
Thereofore $\mathrm{e}^{-az}f(z)$ is a constant function, i.e.,
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-az}f(z)=c,
$$
for some $c\in\mathbb C$ or
$$
f(z)=c\,\mathrm{e}^{-az}.
$$

Comment: thank you. but why i can not solve this problem by CR equation?

Comment: It is possible as well.

Comment: i posted my own solution, but it is so weird. that's why i post this question on here for asking

Comment: This is the most rigorous way of dealing with such problems, as we do not divide by anything we are not sure we are allowed to divide, i.e., by $f(z)$.